# What is the future of complexity theory in black-hole physics and string theory?

Tags: string-theory, black-holes, ads-cft, complex-systems, black-hole-firewall

I found the recent work by Hayden and Harlow and Susskind very fascinating.

I have also heard talks by Scott Aaronson about this emerging connection.

In particular this idea of understanding black-hole physics via quantum error correcting codes.
(and hence expanders?).

How real is this? [...I am particularly interested since I have done a lot of studies in quantum/classical/string black-hole physics and I also work on mathematics of expanders..]

Some years from now will one be able to get opportunity/funding/faculty/post-doc positions to do research in this area?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17581/discussion-between-anna-v-and-curiousone).

Comment: I've removed the discussion here since it was getting a little off topic; feel free to continue in the aforementioned chat room, but do remember our rules on civility.